# Elixir - Convert float to string

Tags: elixir

I am trying to figure out how to convert a float to a string/binary but seems like its not as easy as it looks

```
iex(1)> to_string(1200.00)
"1.2e3"

iex(2)> Float.to_string(1200.00)
"1.2e3"
```

We need "1200.00" to come out...just not in the exponent notation

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Without further details about your usecase, this will give you your desired result:

```
iex(1)> Float.to_string(1200.00, decimals: 2)
"1200.00"
```

It is using erlang's `float_to_binary/2` and will be deprecated in elixir 1.4 (https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.3.2/lib/elixir/lib/float.ex#L225):

```
def to_string(float, options) do
    :erlang.float_to_binary(float, expand_compact(options))
end
```

In elixir 1.8, there still is `Float.to_string/1`. `Float.to_string/2` is deprecated and the suggestion is to use `:erlang.float_to_binary/2` directly.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? All I see is [Float.to_string/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Float.html#to_string/1).

Comment: It's a bit hidden and soon-to-be deprecated: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.3.2/lib/elixir/lib/float.ex#L225
Probably due to concerns with precision inherit in floats. Depending on the usecase this library https://github.com/ericmj/decimal might relevant

Comment: @splatte In that case I'd say then you might want to edit your answer to include the Erlang function that this currently calls, as that's the way it will need to get called in the future: `:erlang.float_to_binary(1200.00, decimals: 2)`.

Comment: @PaulFioravanti thanks you for your hint. I clarified my answer.

Comment: @splatte If it is going to be deprecated in 1.4, any idea what it will be replaced with?

Comment: @sat sorry, no idea

Comment: There still is `Float.to_string/1`. `Float.to_string/2` is deprecated and the suggestion is to use `:erlang.float_to_binary/2` directly.