# Scientific notation in Elixir

Tags: mongodb, elixir

I am pulling some data from mongodb

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "foo",
  "credit": 10000
}
```

For some reason when I get the credit as a `Float` type with the value of `1.0e4` which is equal to `10000`.
How can i parse it to a regular display (10000) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734113/elixir-convert-float-to-string?

Answer (score 2):

To convert a `float` to an `integer` you can use `round/1` or `trunc/1`

```
iex> round(10000.00)
10000

iex> trunc(10000.00)
10000
```

To output a float as an integer string, you can use `:erlang.float_to_binary/2`

```
iex> :erlang.float_to_binary(10000.00, decimals: 0)
"10000"
```